# How to open URLs from a excel sheet to Power Automate "Go to web page"?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have multiple URLs on an excel sheet (RPA_Test) in column A from rows 2 to 5. I want to **Go to web page** by **For each** loop and copy a specific text from each URL.

How do I open the URL one by one and perform the task for each URL available in the sheet?

Comment: With all due respect, what have you tried because what you’re wanting to do is incredibly simple and there is no simpler software than RPA. So please, what have you tried?

Comment: I have a list of URLs of the same website and I want to open them one by one on the browser then copy some text from the web page and store it in an excel sheet.

The problem is I am unable to loop open URLs from an excel sheet one by one to perform the task.

Comment: Can you show your PAD flow as it currently stands?

Comment: Actually I am learning the power automate and unable to do this thing. If possible can you please let demonstrate how to do this as I didn't see any reliable source for this exercise.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not here to do it for you, I'm here to try and solve an issue you have.  At present, your "issue" is against the Stackoverflow community guidelines.